# FTP-like folder with mass copy protection

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, webdav, copy, ftp

This is something I'm trying to find a solution to for a couple of weeks now.

I have a folder on my server which I'd like to share with my partners overseas
but I have a very specific demands from it

-all partners should have access to **view** the main folder.

-each partner should have access to **edit/upload** files on their folder (which is inside the main folder)

-preferably a search function

so far- fairly easy to just use FTP (which I currently use)
the problem started when I was asked to prevent an **easy mass copy of files from the folder**

I know it will always be possible to copy the files one by one if you can view them (or even mass copy with some specific tools or softwares) but a solution like that is totally fine

so I basically want an ftp folder or an online file-manager with good user permissions management which you cant copy its files as simply as copy and paste.

My current best solution is using **"google apps docs"** but its not user-friendly at all and the permissions doesn't work well over different domain names

I also looked up

- http directory listing with custom modules (no upload feature)
- dropbox and dropbox-like softwares
- asp scripts for file-managing (couldnt find one with specific user permissions)

I have a windows server 2008 with IIS7 but this folder doesn't have to be on this server.

Answer (score 0):

There is http://hyla-project.org, but I haven't tried it personnally and it's in french.